# How to implement pixel level collision detection?

Tags: java, collision-detection, pixel, swing

I'm developing a simple game engine for practise purpose, and I used codes like this to do collision detection (fake code):

```
bool PhysicalObject.isCollideWith(rect: PhysicalObject) =>
  x + width >= rect.x && rect.y <= y + height &&
    x <= rect.x + rect.width &&
    y <= rect.y + rect.height
```

But this treats all objects as a rectangle.
What I want is to detect collision when two objects are overlapping on pixel level (I used `java.awt.Graphics` to draw my game objects).

What's the best way of doing that? Can I create a two-dimension array that represent each pixel and store the pointer to the game object that the corresponding pixel belongs to?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that treats everything as a rectangle

Comment: java and bool? java and pointers? Generally you'd check if two objects'rects collide and the check if any pixels collide. (Broadphase then Narrowphase col detection.)

Comment: S/he pointed out that the code is not supposed to be actual code, and "pointers" probably just means "references".

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sorry

Comment: on topic: I think this is a bit depending on what kind of sprite we're talking about. pixel-perfect collision detection isn't easy to implement in my quick view. And I think that this is too advanced for something that should be an simple game, I personally recommend trying to make the collision rectangle at around the important part of the sprite, and smaller than the sprite so the collision hits the least whitespace as possible.

Comment: To help you a bit further, this page explains my statement further: http://www.kilobolt.com/collision-detection-basics  (Friendly reminder that this is just a way to think about a different solution, this is not a clear answer to the question "how to implement pixel level collision?")